# The login server returned an error, please consult the troubleshooting page for more information

Tags: appcelerator, osx-elcapitan, appcelerator-studio

when I try to load Titanium Studio I get the following error:

The login server returned an error Please consult the troubleshooting page for more information.

When I do this:
curl -F "username=XXXX" -F "password=YYYY" https://dashboard.appcelerator.com/api/v1/auth/login

I get "success", after this when I do:

/AppceleratorStudio.app/Contents/MacOS/AppceleratorStudio

I get the same dialog box with logon screen, and I get the same error.

The content of .log of Titanium Workspace is:
Macbook-Pro1:.metadata imac$ tail .log

!SESSION 2016-02-19 22:59:35.244 -----------------------------------------------

eclipse.buildId=unknown

java.version=1.6.0_65

java.vendor=Apple Inc.

BootLoader constants: OS=macosx, ARCH=x86, WS=cocoa, NL=es_XL

Framework arguments:  -keyring /Users/imac/.eclipse_keyring -showlocation

Command-line arguments:  -os macosx -ws cocoa -arch x86 -keyring /Users/imac/.eclipse_keyring -consoleLog -showlocation

!ENTRY org.eclipse.core.net 1 0 2016-02-19 22:59:37.548

!MESSAGE System property http.nonProxyHosts has been set to local|*.local|169.254/16|*.169.254/16 by an external source. This value will be overwritten using the values from the preferences

This happened after I installed the last Java JRE. So, in order to do this, I installed Java from here:

https://support.apple.com/kb/DL1572?viewlocale=en_US&locale=en_US

But it doesn't work!

I would appreciate your help.

My OSX is El Capitan

Answer (score 1):

They have just updated the platform, studio and associated SDKs, I would update and see if you get the same issue, otherwise you may need the latest version of Node.js that is supported by titanium. I had issues with what you had a while ago and updating node fixed it after running other commands.

https://wiki.appcelerator.org/display/guides2/Installing+Node

If node doesn't fix it i'll dig out the terminal commands I had to use.

Comment: It's been a while for me... How can you update the SDKs if Studio won't open?

Comment: sudo npm install -g appcelerator
then
appc setup

Comment: getting this now:  const EventEmitter = require('events').EventEmitter;
^^^^^
SyntaxError: Use of const in strict mode.

Answer (score 1):

You do mean *Titanium Studio* and not *Appcelerator Studio*? Titanium Studio has been discontinued on June 1 2015. You can get Appcelerator Studio here:

http://web.appcelerator.com/product/studio

Comment: Discontinued as in "No longer supported", or discontinued as in "You will no longer be able to use it and we will make sure you don't". I have been able to use it up until about two weeks ago

Comment: Discontinued as in we don't support/develop it anymore and the API it uses for authentication and all is a legacy back-end that at some point will be taken down.